# Smooth scroll issue with position:fixed;

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll

I'm trying to use a smooth scroll effect like this: [Smooth scroll effect](http://www.onlinedesignteacher.com/2017/01/smooth-scrolling-effect-for-website.html)

I've worked out that `position:fixed;` (or absolute) is the root of the problem. It works perfectly if I change this value, but I can't as I have a bg image covering the viewport and cannot work out a way around it.

How do I work around this? I found this [article](https://www.fourkitchens.com/blog/article/fix-scrolling-performance-css-will-change-property/) which I think tackles the problem, but I can't seem to implement it.

The css I'm using to position the background picture looks like this:

```
.bg {
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position:center center; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:fixed;
  background-image: url( http://lorempixel.com/400/200/);
}
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jhyvcgv7/)

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle example reproducing your issue?

Comment: Just included one, but I can't get it to work with jsfiddle - sorry!

Comment: With `position:fixed`, usually are those properties also setted : `top`, `left` and `z-index`.

Comment: No @LouysPatriceBessette, they are not. They are just as listed here.   z-index:0;
  left:0;
  top:0; produces the same results.

Comment: So your problem was the `z-index`.

Comment: no sorry, I mean that adding these values changes nothing

Comment: Have a look [here](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/PjOoaz).

Comment: Perhaps I did not explain adequately, but it is the behaviour of the js I linked in the article I am trying to achieve. It is position:fixed; which is preventing this js from running.

Comment: I'm so sorry - i missed a line of code! This is perfect. Thank you ever so. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I would fix the div in the top left corner without wrapping the whole page contents inside it.

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jhyvcgv7/1/

```
.bg {
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position:center center; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:fixed;
  background-image: url( http://lorempixel.com/400/200/);
  top: 0; 
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: Just curious, why not add the background image and it's properties to the `body` ?

Comment: because of js confusion